# Xcode 11.6 crash after commit on Source Control

Tags: xcode, crash

My development is essentially stopped because of this Xcode problem. Whenever I do a commit, the next time that I open the project what opens in the Project Navigator is not the whole project but just one line: the name of the project. I can get around this by going to Source Tree and unchecking the UserState.xstate file. Then the project opens ok, but if I Build, Xcode immediately crashes with the same crash every time.  Sometimes I can get past this by closing the project, deleting the DerivedData file, quitting and restarting Xcode. I notice that this causes Xcode to re-index.  This used to work, but now even that has stopped working. I submitted a bug report to Apple but have not heard anything. I have tried going into the xcode.project package and deleting the file, but that doesn't work either. I even tried rebooting the Mac but that did not solve the problem either. I'm not putting out the whole crash log because I don't think it will help.  Does this sound like a problem anyone else has seen? Thanks!

Comment: Use Sourcetree, and in Xcode turn off source control entirely in the Source Control pref pane. Does that fix it?

Comment: Also: "I can get around this by going to Source Tree and unchecking the UserState.xstate" The fact that this is visible in Sourcetree at all is a mistake. Your `.gitignore` is faulty. This file should not be under git control.